# Laravel dd not working when I added it to controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, dd

My controller works fine but when I use `dd();` to show something I got `503 services not available error`.

My related section controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Order;
use App\AddMonumentSize;
use App\AddHeadstoneDesign;
use App\ImageColor;
use App\DesignCategory;
use App\Shipping;
use App\Billling;
class DesignController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $headstone = AddHeadstoneDesign::get(); 
        $sizestone = AddMonumentSize::get();
        $colorstone = ImageColor::get();
        $designCategory = DesignCategory::get();
        return view('design.select_size' , compact('headstone' , 'sizestone' , 'colorstone' , 'designCategory'));
    }
```

My route

```
Route::get('designer', 'DesignController@index');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post the code that’s not working too.

Comment: I don't see any `dd()` in that code

Comment: 503 Service Unavailable The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state. I guess it is not connected with dd()

Comment: Where is the `dd()` line?

Comment: I try this code just by add dd($request); that not works but by return back(); or redirect() it works fine?

Comment: @ishegg I also create a new controller just by an index and store method to show request data but I give this error again1